# Listening comprehension

Tags: listening-comprehension, conversation

Can someone please tell me what they are saying from 00:20 and forward in this audio file? Thank you very much advance

https://sndup.net/6ky7

Comment: Could you please write down, what you understand already and leave gaps for the words you don't understand? That way you could display your own efforts - and people might help you on how to fill the gaps using the context you already understood.

Comment: On https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483849/making-out-the-meaning-of-words/483866#483866 a similar kind of questions is asked ... and it wasn't shut down by moderators. Indeed, one of the comments was that it was a great addition to the usual style of question.

Comment: @user02814 The OP of the linked question wrote down what they understood and highlighted the unclear parts. This is missing in the above question. Without showing this effort, there is the suspicion that someone wants to get done their homework by us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By 00:20 in your audio she is saying: "Zusatzzahl" (that would mean *additional number*) and after them she said "neun" (9, nine).

Comment: And to explain what a "Zusatzzahl" is, or was: The literal meaning is "additional number". In the lottery "6 aus 49" you bet on 6 numbers from 1 to 49. Until 2013 you could additionally choose a seventh "Zusatzzahl". If you already scored a win by getting, say, 4 of the 6 chosen numbers right, the correct "Zusatzzahl" increased the payout. In the rule change of 2013, the "Zusatzzahl" was replaced by the "Superzahl", which has a different concept.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the time you're sparing to answer my questions.

Comment: gladly done, have fun by learning german!